# Flutter ios cloud_firestore giving errors

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a problem with cloud_firestore plugin, I created an app before with this plugin and it worked fine, I download GoogleService-info and in xcode I put this document in runner folder, next to info.plist, but when I try to work with a new project throw me 7 exceptions and then the screen in app turn in black and exited.

```
launching lib/main.dart on iPhone Xʀ in debug mode...

Xcode build done. 17.8s

Configuring the default Firebase app...

*** First throw call stack:

0 CoreFoundation 0x0000000114d498db __exceptionPreprocess + 331
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00000001142ecac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
2 CoreFoundation 0x0000000114d49735 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
3 Runner 0x000000010f4ccbfa +[FIRApp configure] + 138
4 Runner 0x000000010f99ebd6 -[FLTCloudFirestorePlugin init] + 214

5 Runner 0x000000010c96176c +[FLTCloudFirestorePlugin registerWithRegistrar:] + 300

6 Runner 0x000000010c343fb0 +[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] + 112

7 Runner <…>

Error connecting to the service protocol: HttpException: , uri =

Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably adding the file without Xcode:

1. open the ios the project in Xcode
2. drag and drop `GoogleService-info` in Runner/Runner
   [image]
3. the file `ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` need to be changed automatically by Xcode.

Comment: thanks for your answer :).
I did it all the time, but only in one project works well, in all the others, throw me the error

Comment: So simple! Thanks a lot for that. This answer should be marked as the correct one